# Sci-Fi: Story about an astronaut and telepathic feline-like aliens

Tags: story-identification, soft-sci-fi

I read a series of books when I was younger, about 20 years ago. And I can't for the life of me remember one title, or the writer. So I'm asking for your help.

Things I know:

1. The writer was Scandinavian. Or a name that looks/sounds Scandinavian
2. I read the Dutch translations. So I don't know if English versions exist.
3. A man lives and works in a giant dome on a planet that is not Earth.
4. I think the planet is Venus.
5. The atmosphere is hazardous to some materials. The planet is jungle-like.
6. One day during maintenance the man has an accident and is
   unconscious or something. He would die if he doesn't get back into
   the dome. He doesn't make it, and the atmosphere eats away his
   protective gear. He doesn't die; instead his lungs adjust to the
   atmosphere. He can walk around the planet naked just fine. Basically everything that is not biological corrodes away.
7. He discovers indigenous species that look like large cats or panthers.
   They seem to communicate telepathically. He can either hear them if
   they "speak" to him, or they understand him telepathically.
8. He forms a bond with one of the aliens.

The rest is pretty hazy, but I hope someone read these books as well and can point me into the right direction.

EDIT: some vague details I remember:

9. The aliens live in a large cave system.

   10. There was something about hunting. Since they were a predatory species (like cats) they talk about attacking from down-wind. But because they are telepathic, they could attack larger enemies by coordinating the attacks.

Answer (score 8):

There are a lot of parallels, as well as a lot of mismatches, but my best guess is "Sentenced to Prism", by Alan Dean Foster.

The premise of the story is a handyman/adventurer is sent to an unknown world to figure out why a scientific colony sent there to determine it's colonization or mineral worth has stopped reporting in.

He is sent in with a high level hazard exoskeleton, which degrades in short order.  He has to abandon it, even though he doesn't think he's going to survive without it.  He ends up making mistakes and has to be rescued by one of the local intelligent life forms.  He forms an attachment to this creature for most of the rest of the book.

The local intelligent community talk through a version of radio frequency, which he has to use a wireless implant to understand.  They help him and vice versa.  Many of the creatures are explained to be about large cat or dog sized, but they range in many sizes, shapes, and function.

I'm not going further than this, so I can avoid any spoilers.  Hopefully I've described enough for the OP to decide if this is the book or not.  It's a great novel, but I'm not sure it's a match.  It's close, though.

Edit: The alien that saves the MC's life acts like a cat.  It sits on his shoulder to maintain "wired" communication until the implant can be made, and sleeps on or near the MC, since his silicon body works better at night with the MC's body heat, which the alien doesn't produce.

Comment: Thanks for your input, it indeed sounds very similar. I'm looking it up, but I think it is a different story.
My story is definitely part of a series of books.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not the story I'm looking for.

Comment: Well, I didn't think so, but people's memory can significantly alter their perception of a story after 20 years.  Hope you find the right one!

Answer (score 5):

From [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/21641/4495):

> you might mean **Torenhoog en Mijlenbreed** by Tonke Dragt (translated to German as *Turmhoch und meilenweit. Ein Zukunftsroman*). This story includes the desintegration of unnatural materials, like some clothing. Cotton clothes, for instance, remain intact. The Venusians are telepaths and only a few humans have enough ability to understand them. The main character's name is Edu.

This was not a series though; it was just the one book and a sequel: *Ogen van Tijgers*.

Comment: I came across this book also. It also has a lot of similar elements. But it is unfortunately not it.

Comment: @Whacko OK. As far as I remember, all the points you mentioned seemed to fit, so I was sure I had a match. But can you remember some points of difference? I mean, can you say "no, this book had this, while the book I remember had that"? Then you can add a new item to your list.

Comment: I'm trying to think of more details. But one thing I do remember is that it was translated to Dutch, because I wanted to do a book report about it. I wasn't allowed because the writer was foreign, so that rules out Tonke Dragt

Comment: Thinking of your answer makes me doubt myself more and more. Maybe I did read "Torenhoog en Mijlenbreed", maybe BECAUSE I wasn't allowed to read my own choice. The aliens being humanoid makes more sense too, because of point 10 of the details I listed. The predatory species could be the panther-like creatures.